Forbidden, in Wildfly server this is what i get when i access a deployed application
I deployed a Spring boot apache camel application in the wildfly server.
If I try to access the application I get a "Forbidden" error in Browser.
I created a management user, I dropped a .war file of the application in the wildfly server. I clicked on context root. Then I got the above-described problem.
I am using wildfly 27.

Without more details it is hard to tell what is happening

I have created a simple spring boot camel application, which has a simple route, http://localhost:8080/camel/hello it sends a "hello world". It works locally. So now I built a .war file using the command "mvn clean package". Now i deployed this .war file in wildfly server, but when i access the application from the server i am getting forbidden. I created a web.xml after going through some articles, i created a welcome page which is working but i cannot access the above written route.

Do you use Java EE / Jakarta EE 8 code ? because WildFly 27 is Jakarta EE 10
